# How to detect certain scroll position with framer-motion?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

When scrollTop is equal to 500px, I want to trigger an animation on a div with position fixed. Is there a way to do this in framer-motion. I only find solution that propose when element is in viewport. But my div is always in the viewport, because it has a fixed position. I need a build in scroll position watcher.

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animate-in-view-gqcc8?file=/src/index.js)

```
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";
import { motion, useAnimation } from "framer-motion";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is kind of old already but here is the answer.

```html
import { useViewportScroll } from "framer-motion";

const Nav = () => {
    const { scrollY } = useViewportScroll();
    
    scrolly.onChange(y => {
    // y = scroll position
    //Do Something
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  const { scrollY } = useViewportScroll();

  scrollY.onChange(y => {
    console.log('y ', y)
  })
```

just a slight typo :)

Comment: Where's the typo you're referring to? The answer box should only be used for complete answers

Comment: @camille `scrolly` instead of `scrollY`. Anyways, you have a sharp eye but as camille says, answer boxes should be used for answers. You can get some more reputation then comment on that answer to point it out.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are interested in latest version.

```
import { useScroll } from "framer-motion"

const { scrollY } = useScroll()

useMotionValueEvent(scrollY, "change", (latest) => {
  console.log("Page scroll: ", latest)
})
```